# How instanciate a generic entity with an embedded signal?

Tags: vhdl

Iam using a package for state_values:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package States is

   type state_values is (ST0,ST1,ST2,ST3,ST4,ST5,ST6,ST7,ST8,ST9,ST10,ST11,ST12,ST13,ST14,ST15,ST16);
   signal pres_state, next_state: state_values;


end States;
```

This is my component, with a generic entity:

```
component NextStateLogic
    generic (

                BLRH       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0); 
                pres_state : state_values := ST0;
                next_state : state_values := ST0);
        end component;
```

In the code there are several embedded signals to use for comunication between components:

```
    signal LRH_int        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    signal next_state_int : state_values := ST0;
    signal pres_state_int : state_values := ST0;
    signal Clk1Hz_int     : STD_LOGIC;
```

At the instanciate shows me the next error:

```
The actual value (Signal 'LRH_int') associated with a generic must be a globally static expression.
```

Investigating, I cannot connect signals to generics, I can use constanst but this ones are no useful to the propuse of the code.
Is there a way to instanciate the generic component with and another type of embedded signals?

Comment: Signals connect to ports, not generics (and I would use the package for types and functions, but not signal declarations, even of those types)

Answer (score 1):

**Generics** are used for everything that configures a component before the code is synthesized. E.g., you could have a generic that configures the width of your input and ouput signals.

**Ports** are used for everything that changes dynamically during runtime, e.g., data signals clocks etc.

Therefore it is not sensible to have an entity (or component) with only a generic map, because it would never do anything in hardware. Use a **port** definition.